# loginwindow Notification or Getting the notification about user logout

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

Is it possible to get the notification to my pre-login agent when the users logs out? Not the fast user switch notifications (NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActiveNotification and NSWorkspaceSessionDidResignActiveNotification). This works but only for fast user switching, at least that I understand. I can access the last logout information from utmpx dictionary with my daemon but how do i tell it to run the search on loginwindow? Is it possible to do it within a SIGTERM handler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found what I was looking for. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1133/_index.html
SystemConfiguration framework will do the trick if anyone ever asks.